# background image divider won't show in my css menu

Tags: html, css, image, list, menu

I'm using an image divider in my css menu however the last one at the end of the contact button won't show up..

```
    <div id="menu">
<ul>
<li><a href="index.html"><span class="used">Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
<li><a href="contect.html">Contact</a></li>
<img src="img/divider.png" alt="" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thats my menu (ignore the divider.png as that is the image below the menu), 
and this is my css.

```
.header #menu {
word-spacing: 60px;
font: 17px 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
color: #333;
margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
width: 1024px;
overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
    width: 239px;
    height: 69px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: url(../img/nav-divider.png) no-repeat 0 100%;
}
```

As you can my background image is my divider and it works for all the other list items just after the contact list item it wont appear anyone help, it's been driving me nuts.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/eCdvs/

Comment: check your image path is it correct ?

Comment: yeah image path is fine all the images show up apart from the last one after the contact menu item.. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the image path like this:

background-image: background-image:url('images/image.png');

This should help.

Comment: http://i42.tinypic.com/21b3j84.jpg

that but I need another divider after the contact text and the text I need to be more inline with the divider images not at the top of them if you know what I mean..

Comment: Use min-width instead width in header class css and remove height from li {}

Comment: cancel that if i add a blank list item it doesnt sit properly

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when I took out the css stuff from the img tag, i.e.

```
<img src="img/divider.png" alt="" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;"/>
```

to

```
<img src="img/divider.png" alt=""/>
```

it also worked by removing this img tag and replacing with a blank list item, i.e. `<li></li>`

Comment: I added another blank <li></li> item and it worked this way for me thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is the screenshot of my code written here, that red color bg is an image]

check your image path and try this.. 
if you are writing style in css file,

use this : `background: url(../img/nav-divider.png) no-repeat 0 100%;`

if you are writing inside html page use this : `background: url(img/nav-divider.png) no-repeat 0 100%;`

```
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
        #menu {
    font: 17px 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #333;
    margin: 40px auto 0 auto;
    width: 1024px;
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    ul {
        list-style: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    li {
        list-style: none;
        width: 19%;
        height: 69px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: baseline;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: url(../img/nav-divider.png) no-repeat 0 100%;
    }
    a{
        color: white;
        line-height: 69px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    </style>



 <div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html"><span class="used">Home</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="contect.html">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="contect.html">Contact2</a></li>
    <li><a href="contect.html">Contact3</a></li>

    </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: there isn't a difference in which styles you are referring too?